# Nsis show admin name and password prompt while installing as user

Tags: window, windows-installer, admin, nsis

I have an nsis script creating installer. One of the requirements is if user is not admin then he gets an option to install in local data folder or in program files.
In case of install to program files - there must a prompt for admin username and password. After a long searches I have not found anything.
I added this function:
`Function RequestAdminRights MessageBox MB_OK "inside RequestAdminRights" ; Request admin rights if not already running as admin UserInfo::GetAccountType Pop $0 StrCmp $0 "admin" +2 SetShellVarContext all ExecShell "" "runas" '"$EXEPATH" /S _?=$INSTDIR' MessageBox MB_OK "running as shell" FunctionEnd`
But when installing I get error opening for writing popup.
Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

`_?=` is only for the uninstaller. For the installer, `/S /D=$INSTDIR` but I'm not sure if running the installer silently here is the best option? And ExecShell would have to be `ExecShell "runas" "$EXEPATH" '/S /D=$INSTDIR'`.

I would perhaps recommend that you use [MultiUser](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/MultiUser/Readme.html) and [highest as the execution level](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Examples/MultiUser.nsi). This will allow admins to install to LocalAppData or ProgramFiles and normal users to LocalAppData. A normal user would have to right-click the installer and choose "Run as Administrator" to unlock the ProgramFiles mode.

If this is unacceptable the you would have to create something like MultiUser but when ProgramFiles is chosen and `UserInfo::GetAccountType` does not return admin, you would then ExecShell yourself again with the runas verb (and without /S).

Comment: My goal is that user - if he is not admin - on install gets an option to install to local data folder (for himself only) or in program files (for all users) . if for all users option selected - then he must get a window to insert admin credentials and script must verify these credentials. Problem is I cannot find any example of it, and you are right - I do no need silent install in this case.

Comment: You will not find many examples because it is too difficult to get right. To elevate you have to create a new process and it can't just take over the UI at that point, it has to be a new window.